# Rollback gems according to version in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to revert back to an older set of gems in my dev environment. I've replaced my `Gemfile.lock` file with the old versions I need.

I thought I could just replace the `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install`, but that doesn't seem to work. When I do that, then check the gem version numbers, I get the same versions I had before.

One of the gems I need to downgrade is the `rake` gem. The version I need is `11.1.2` but currently when I do `gem list` I get `rake (12.0.0, 11.1.2, 10.4.2)`

How can I revert `rake` and all the other gems back to their previous versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed..  `gem uninstall <gem name>` and then if there are multiple gems you can pick which version you want to uninstall!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to clean out old gems no longer in your `Gemfile.lock`, you can run `bundle clean`.

However, even though the gems are still there, they are not being used if you run a task with `bundle exec`.

Comment: No, not gems no longer being used, but actually the new versions of gems that I don't want. Just trying to go backwards on my gem versions